# Where does it say "in-between worlds"?

Tags: reference-request, worldly

I don't know where I am getting all these ideas; perhaps it's my failing memory, or whatever.  But which sutta does it say something about, "...in-between worlds..."?  I'm fairly certain I read this in the text...bummer i can't find it...what quality standard?

Comment: Or in between bodies?

Comment: @ruben2020 hmm..no i suppose the word i'm considering is world, or realm, or dimension, etc..

Comment: i suppose it's good to think of this as some kind of useful fabrication anyway, since it's just satisfying me in a very temporary way...

Comment: @lilredindy another dumb question

Comment: @lilredindy perhaps this, but not sure...https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/KN/StNp/StNp5_4.html#stnp_note5.4.03, see footnotes

Answer (score 2):

> "“Bhikkhus, there are world interstices, vacant and abysmal regions of blinding darkness and gloom, where the light of the sun and moon, so powerful and mighty, does not reach.”" ~~ [SN 56.46](https://suttacentral.net/sn56.46/en/bodhi?reference=none&highlight=false) ~~

Answer (score 0):

Although the phrasing is not identical, a possible explanation for "in-between world" can be found [here](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn35/sn35.095.than.html):

*"Then, Malunkyaputta, with regard to phenomena to be seen, heard, sensed, or cognized: In reference to the seen, there will be only the seen. In reference to the heard, only the heard. In reference to the sensed, only the sensed. In reference to the cognized, only the cognized. That is how you should train yourself. When for you there will be only the seen in reference to the seen, only the heard in reference to the heard, only the sensed in reference to the sensed, only the cognized in reference to the cognized, then, Malunkyaputta, there is no you in connection with that. When there is no you in connection with that, there is no you there. When there is no you there, you are neither here nor yonder nor between the two. This, just this, is the end of stress."*